"Request" is not a member of custom ROS service
I'm learning how to use the Robot Operating System (noetic version) and i've followed the services tutorial. I've created the basic service detailed in this tutorial and now i've attempted to create one that uses one of my custom messages defined in the msg folder of my package:
std_msgs/Header reqtime
int32 charger_id
---
std_msgs/Header resptime
intro_tutorial/vacstatus response

However, when i try to use this in the same way in a server i get a strange error.
This is my service provider code:
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "intro_tutorial/vacupdate.h"
#include "intro_tutorial/vacstatus.h"

bool vacstatus_service(intro_tutorial::vacstatus::Request &req,
    intro_tutorial::vacstatus::Response &res)
{
    ROS_INFO(
            "Receiving request from station [%ld]",
            (int)req.charger_id
        );
    res.resptime.time = Time.now();
    ROS_INFO(
            "sending back response"
        );

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "vacuum_server");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::ServiceServer service =
        n.advertiseService("vacstatus_service", vacstatus_service);
    ROS_INFO("Ready to public vacuum status data.");
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}

And this is the error i get:
error: ‘Request’ is not a member of ‘intro_tutorial::vacstatus’ {aka ‘intro_tutorial::vacstatus_<std::allocator<void> >’}
    5 | bool vacstatus_service(intro_tutorial::vacstatus::Request &req,

What is causing this? The service itself compiles without error in the project, and i've added everything in my CMakeLists.txt just like in the tutorial
EDIT: I get the analogous error for Response

I made a simple mistake: vacstatus was the message i was using inside the service. After switching to vacupdate it works fine

It is great that you post the answer, however you should also accept it (using the 'V' icon on the left of the answer) so that the question becomes marked as 'answered'.

i intended to but i need to wait another day to be able to
